# Prove O(max{ f (n),g(n)}) = O( f (n)+g(n))

Tags: big-o

I'm a bit confused with Big O notation and how to prove it when there is a max.  How do I prove O(max{ f (n),g(n)}) = O( f (n)+g(n)) with the max?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the time complexity of computing maximum value of f(n) and g(n). Calculating the maximum of two numbers is a constant time operation*. Calculating the left argument takes O(f(n)) and the right argument takes O(g(n)). So the time complexity of O(max{f(n),g(n)}) O(1) + O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) which simplifies to O(f(n) + g(n)).

*Note: Taking the maximum of two values is a constant time operation in a computer, but computers are not turing machines. For large numbers determining the maximum of two numbers is linear in the size of the number.

Assuming you mean the order of maximum time complexity of f(n) and g(n). Then you use the fact that because of the max the run time will either be O(f(n)) or O(g(n)). And because O(f(n) + g(n)) > O( f(n)), and O(f(n) + g(n)) > O( g(n)) the complexity holds for every possible out come. It is a bit cheap but the upper bound doesn't have to be tight.